# Why my lazy navigation property is Null when i'm consuming it in an async method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-6

I try to convert my code to by async and get more performance. My code need to take items from the database and start 4 tasks with the same item. In the example below, i'm printing the property **Offre.TypeOffre.Name**. But the problem with the async version is that the navigation property **TypeOffre** is null and i don't know why. The same code works good in the non-async version.

- the TypeOffre object is lazy loaded from EntityFramework. The first one to access the navigation property will send an sql query to the database.

### Version before converting

```
public void AnalyseOffre()
{
    var offres = context.Offres.ToList();
    var firstOffre = offres.First();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        DoSomething(firstOffre);
    }
}

private void DoSomething(Offre offre)
{
    var value = offre.TypeOffre?.Name ?? "null";

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("value = {0}", value));
}
```

**Result**

- joe
- joe
- joe
- joe

### async version

```
public async Task AnalyseOffre()
{
    var offres = await context.Offres.ToListAsync();
    var firstOffre = offres.First();

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoSomething(firstOffre)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task DoSomething(Offre offre)
{
    var value = offre.TypeOffre?.Name ?? "null";

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("value = {0}", value));
}
```

**Result**

- null
- null
- joe
- joe

Comment: The object you are trying to access is probably not thread safe.

Comment: Looks like `offre.TypeOffre` access is tripping you up. As @YacoubMassad mentioned, it's almost certain that this property is not thread-safe. You'll have to find a way to preload it before you spin up your `Task`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, i searched the web about using lazy loading and async method but i haven't found anything. It seems that nobody is talking about this kind of problem.

Comment: Are there any more warnings on code, other than the one saying you have an `async` method without any `await`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado only the "you have an async method without any await"

Comment: And what does that tell you?